# How to enable SparkListener in Spark on YARN?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

While SparkListener does work when I use Spark in standalone mode, it doesn't work when I run Spark on a cluster over Yarn. Is it possible for SparkListener to work when running over Yarn? If so, what steps should I do to enable that?

Comment: `SparkListener` is a trait for common Spark listeners. Which one exactly are you referring to. If I also may ask, what do you want to use it for?

Comment: I want to check the sizes of cached RDDs and also notify whenever an RDD is finished processing.

Comment: How do you enable the custom SparkListener -- `SparkContext` or Spark property? Can you check Environment page if the setting does include it? I don't see a reason why it couldn't work in Spark on YARN (unless there's a bug to hunt down).